# Magento2: How to remove created eav attributes when uninstalling a Module with Setup/uninstall.php ( removeAttribute)

Tags: php, magento2

I created a module JuistdIT_CustomAttributeCustomer to add custom eav attributes to the customer entity. I added the functionality to the Setup/InstallData.php file by using addAttribute.

```
  $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'test_2', [
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'Test 2',
        'input' => 'text',
        'required' => false,
        'visible' => true,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'sort_order' => 1000,
        'position' => 1000,
        'system' => 0,
        //"backend"  => "",
        //"source"   => "",
        "default" => "",
        //"frontend" => "",
        //"unique"     => false,
        //"note"       => ""
        'is_used_in_grid' => true,
        'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
        'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
        'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,

    ]);
```

However when I uninstall the module with:

```
php bin/magento module:uninstall JuistdIT_CustomAttributeCustomer
```

I want all added EAV attributes to be deleted when I uninstall the module. So I added an Setup/uninstal.php script, where I would like to use the removeAttribute function:

```
$customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "test_2");
```

But the ModuleDataSetupInterface is not available in the uninstall and therefor I cannot use :

```
 public function uninstall(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{

    $setup->startSetup();

    /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
$customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
$customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "test_2");
```

Can someone help me to use the removeAttribute function in the uninstall function of the "class Uninstall implements UninstallInterface"

Thanks

Comment: I'm also wondering about it, did you find an answer ?